# Unison source compile errors in OCAML

Tags: ocaml, unison

I am trying to compile the unison source using OCAML compiler(ver 4.01.0) and GNU make 4.0. The source code is taken from the link (http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison//download/releases/unison-2.27.57/)

I extracted the tar.gz and then wrote the command "make NATIVE=false" as mentioned in the user manual (http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html) see section building unison from scratch windows.

Code starts compiling for few seconds but stops and following errors appear:

----------

```html
File "/cygdrive/c/unison_build/unison-2.27.57/update.ml", line 1:
Error: The implementation /cygdrive/c/unison_build/unison-2.27.57/update.ml
does not match the interface update.cmi:
...
In module NameMap:
The field `split' is required but not provided
In module NameMap:
The field `choose' is required but not provided
In module NameMap:
The field `max_binding' is required but not provided
In module NameMap:
The field `min_binding' is required but not provided
In module NameMap:
The field `bindings' is required but not provided
In module NameMap:
The field `cardinal' is required but not provided
In module NameMap:
The field `partition' is required but not provided
In module NameMap:
The field `filter' is required but not provided
In module NameMap:
The field `exists' is required but not provided
In module NameMap:
The field `for_all' is required but not provided
In module NameMap:
The field `merge' is required but not provided
In module NameMap:
The field `singleton' is required but not provided
Makefile.OCaml:339: recipe for target 'update.cmo' failed
make: *** [update.cmo] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you consider installing Linux on your own machine? Have you been able to install Ocaml from its source code on your machine?

Comment: I found make wasn't installed properly. So OCAML now compiles but the source file has some errors as compiler complains about fields not provide

Comment: An example of the error is "       In module NameMap:
       The field `split' is required but not provided
"

Comment: Are you familiar with Ocaml? BTW, you should edit your question to improve it (by giving the commands and the error messages, indented by four spaces at start of each line)

Comment: Also give the version of ocaml you are using

Comment: I am not familiar with Ocaml but have read intro about the language. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 3):

I got the exact same error (with ocaml 3.12) and solved it by patching file `update.mli` as follows (4th line):

```
-module NameMap : Map.S with type key = Name.t
+module NameMap : MyMap.S with type key = Name.t
```

Note that this is a known bug ([bug #585453](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=585453)) and I got the patch from debian package [here](http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/u/unison2.32.52/unison2.32.52_2.32.52-7.debian.tar.gz) (file `0005-Fix-build-with-OCaml-3.12.patch`). The patch is valid at least for 2.27.57 and 2.32.52. In the same package you can also find a patch for Ocaml 4 it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You should compile Unison with OCaml 3.12, it will not compile with later compilers. Nate that Unison is not under active development anymore:

> Unison is no longer under active development as a research project. At this point, there is no one whose job it is to add new features, fix bugs, or answer questions.

The quote is from the website.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you compiled update.ml using different versions of the OCaml compiler, you clear the _build directory and try again from the beginning.

Comment: I deleted the _build folder, all CMI and CMO files. Still get the same error.

Comment: can you post what is "..." in the error message that you get ?